# Mapping URL to .html extension with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm running a simple Spring Boot 2.0.4 MVC application with Thymeleaf. I have 2 controllers. The first, IndexController.java, maps the URL "localhost:8080/" to the template index.html. The second, ProductController.java, maps the URL "localhost:8080/product" to the template product.html. On the index.html template, I have a link to the product template:

```
     <a href="product.html">
```

When I run the project and hover over this link in a browser, the URL that is displayed is "localhost:8080/product.html". If I click on the link, I get a 404 error. If I manually enter "localhost:8080/product" into the URL box of the browser, the product page is displayed correctly. So I can't get the URL "localhost:8080/product.html" to work. I thought with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, any extension, "localhost:8080/product[.*]", would work out of the box.

I created this project via IntelliJ 2018, using the built in Spring Boot configurator. I have only one configuration file, SfgThymeleafCourseApplication.java:

```
package guru.springframework;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SfgThymeleafCourseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(SfgThymeleafCourseApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My index controller is IndexController.java:

```
package guru.springframework.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {
       return "index";
    }

}
```

My product controller ProductController.java:

```
package guru.springframework.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

   @RequestMapping("/product")
   public String getProduct() {
     return "product";
   }
}
```

My POM looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>sfg-thymeleaf-course</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sfg-thymeleaf-course</name>
<description>Thymeleaf Course</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `<a href="product">Product<\a>` should work, remove the `.html` part.

Comment: Do you need both `localhost:8080/product` and `localhost:8080/product.html` to work?  What happens if you change your controller to `@RequestMapping("/product.html")` and access `localhost:8080/product.html`

Comment: I don't need both, I'm just wondering why the code on Git works for both, but my version only works for localhost:8080/product, when I can't find a significant difference between the two in terms of source code.

Comment: Ignore this comment.

Comment: The original author of this code uses the tag <a href="product" th:href="@{/product.html}"> along with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.1.RELEASE If I use this <a> tag, and change to version 1.3.1, I get the expected result, I can use the URLs "localhost:8080/product" or "localhost:8080/product.html". But if I put the spring-boot-starter-parent back to the value I was using, 2.0.4, then I get a 404 when I try to access localhost:8080/parent.html".